# How can I convert images to bytes and bytes to image?

Tags: iphone, ios

How to convert images to bytes and send out to a stream, then receive bytes from the input stream, and convert the bytes into images again?

Answer (score 7):

For getting bytes from an image:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, imageQuality);
```

For getting an image from bytes:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

BTW, If you need the bytes from the NSData just call its bytes method.

Answer (score 2):

`UIImage` to byte array

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *byteArray  = [data base64Encoding];
```

Byte array to `UIImage`

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:YOUR_BYTE_ARRAY length:ARRAY_LENGTH];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
```

Hope you found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Convert image into bytes like this:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage.image);  
NSUInteger len = [imageData length];
Byte *byteData= (Byte*)malloc(len);
[imageData  getBytes:byteData length:len];
```

Now byte into image like this:

```
NSData *pictureData = [NSData dataWithBytes:byteData];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:pictureData];
```